# How could I have gotten the Cyrillic spelling of Vladyka?

Tags: правописание

I'm not sure that this is exactly a Russian language question as technology and languages, but...

I was looking for the Cyrillic spelling of "Vladyka", and the Google Translate iPhone app doesn't offer the full web translate.google.com app option of typing something in Latin characters and get help spelling it in Cyrillic. So I tried "English to Russian" in the app, which seems much less rich than the desktop translate.google.com, and then completely failed to find a preimage that would render as "Владыка." "Bishop" was translated as "епископ", and I was pretty sure "lord" was going to translate as "господин".

In terms of general strategies, what can / should I be doing to identify correct spelling when I only have a smartphone, not a desktop? (Type it in a Google search?)

Thanks,

Comment: https://translate.yandex.com/

Comment: Владыка is an addressing title for an Orthodox bishop, not unlike "Your Excellency"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can install a Russian dictionary in keyboard apps (at least in Android there's plenty of them), and it contains most of the language, except neologisms.

If you have a transliterated Russian word, there are Russian<->Translit (транслит) services:

- live translation (write in translit, see in Russian): http://translit.cc/ **(with spellchecking)**
- another useful site: http://pereklad.online.ua/translit-russkiy/
- quite old and ugly one: http://www.russpain.ru/translit-avtomat.htm

Comment: Also in web version of google translate, if you choose Russian as source language and start typing Latin letters it will suggest Cyrillic spelling